# Change of Python3 is not recognized

Tags: python3

I am testing different versions on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal following this [tutorial](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/).

**Problem** Command `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` is not able to switch between different alternatives of Python3 (see the detail below). This is confirmed when `python3 -V` returns the system version, rather than the version of the selected alternative

**Installing multiple python versions**
TL;DR the [tutorial](https://hackersandslackers.com/multiple-python-versions-ubuntu-20-04/) installs multiple versions of Python from `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` repository. Once the versions are installed, the `python3` command is made into alternatives:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1 
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 3
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2
```

Then using the `sudo update-alternatives --config python3` command, one can select different alternatives to `python3` command:

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

  Selection    Path                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/python3.10   1         manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/python3.8    2         manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/python3.9    3         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Running `python3 -V` returns **Python 3.9.7** no matter what alternative is selected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually very simple. Running `which python3` I found out that there is one more installation on my system in **/home//anaconda3/bin**, which the system wise installation are in **/usr/bin**. Adding the Anaconda3 path, I can switch among all versions seamlessly.